# Form button -Save & clear,Save& next

Tags: php, forms, laravel, submit, reset

I am using laravel5.4. I am working on form. I have to add three buttons like Clear All, Save & Clear, Save & Next button.For Clear All, I have added

```
<button type="reset" value="reset" class="btn btn-primary">
    Clear All
</button>
```

For Save & clear,my requirement is to save the input data entered by user and clear all input fields to make the user enter another data in form.

For Save & Next, my requirement is to save all the input data entered by user and make student name input field, subject input field,Teacher Input field selected by user remain same and clear rest input fields in form.

A user can select student name, subject name, teacher name from the dropdown list and can enter multiple inputs for the same student, subject, teacher. So I need to keep all these three unchanged and clear rest input fields to enter new data.

Please suggest on how to implement this.

Comment: `type="reset"` is handled by the browser directly. You won't get any request to the server with that.

Comment: you can  do all these stuff  using jquery ajax

Answer (score 1):

Name all 3 buttons differently, then in your controller just handle each in which ever way you require.

So for save and reset you'd listen for the save-reset button and return the form for another entry, whereas if it's save-next return the next form.

Eg:

```
Public function handleFormAction(Request $request){
    If(isset($request->input('save-next')){
        // Do something
    }else if(isset($request->input('save-next')){
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Or instead of names you could use button values

```
If($request->input('save-button') == 'save-reset')){}
```

As previously mentioned you can let the browser handle the simple reset action.